# Can I test the difference between subjects in a GLMM?

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, glmm

I have the following GLMM model (using R with the lme4 package):

```
resp ~ condition * level + (1 | subject)
```

I have a clear difference between levels and I would like to see now if there is a difference between subjects within levels. Is this possible? If so, after filtering by group `(df %>% filter(group == level1))` would this model be suitable:

Formula:

```
 resp ~ condition + subject + (1 | subject)
```

GLMM is still quite new to me. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

There are actually quite a few ways to examine random effects, but not a lot of ways to *test* them if you mean inferential tests (I note some exceptions near the end of my answer).

#### Exploring RE's Descriptively

I have fit a really basic model with some data in the languageR package in R to show how. First, the packages and the model fit are shown below. Here I have used a crossed random effects design, which uses subjects and items as random intercepts.

```
#### Load Libraries ####
library(languageR)
library(lmerTest)
library(tidyverse)
library(performance)

#### Fit Model ####
fit <-  lmer(LogRT 
             ~  PC1 
             + PC2 
             + PC3
             + (1|Word)
             + (1|Subject),
             data = beginningReaders)
```

To check the model metrics of the `lme4` fit, we can use the `model_performance` function from the performance package by running `model_performance(fit)`. One of the nice things it gives beyond a number of other useful stats is the ICC:

```
# Indices of model performance

AIC      |     AICc |      BIC | R2 (cond.) | R2 (marg.) |   ICC |  RMSE | Sigma
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
6213.114 | 6213.128 | 6261.957 |      0.377 |      0.225 | 0.195 | 0.342 | 0.347
```

Here we can see that the ICC is around 19.5% indicating a fair level of clustering, but nothing super high. Running `summary(fit)` seems to indicate why, as the variation for both subjects and words seems low:

```
Linear mixed model fit by REML. t-tests use Satterthwaite's method [
lmerModLmerTest]
Formula: LogRT ~ PC1 + PC2 + PC3 + (1 | Word) + (1 | Subject)
   Data: beginningReaders

REML criterion at convergence: 6199.1

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-5.3367 -0.6301 -0.0247  0.6318  3.9126 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 Word     (Intercept) 0.01154  0.1074  
 Subject  (Intercept) 0.01763  0.1328  
 Residual             0.12014  0.3466  
Number of obs: 7923, groups:  Word, 184; Subject, 59

Fixed effects:
              Estimate Std. Error         df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  7.336e+00  1.944e-02  7.611e+01 377.407  < 2e-16 ***
PC1          1.351e-01  3.397e-03  6.816e+03  39.785  < 2e-16 ***
PC2          5.608e-02  5.381e-03  7.772e+03  10.423  < 2e-16 ***
PC3         -2.836e-02  5.804e-03  7.807e+03  -4.886 1.05e-06 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
    (Intr) PC1    PC2   
PC1 -0.015              
PC2  0.000  0.002       
PC3  0.002 -0.008  0.005
```

The summary is dense, but basically the "Random effects" section shows that subjects and words vary fairly little (less than 1 SD). However, some subjects and some words may vary more than others. We can check with `ranef(fit)`. This output shows how much the conditional mean shifts with each word and each subject:

```
$Word
              (Intercept)
avontuur    -0.0376961757
baden        0.0929130421
balkon       0.0550390452
band        -0.0699927051
barsten      0.1364986648
beek        -0.0941336459
beker       -0.0677617070
beton        0.0198963592
beven       -0.0584016778
bieden       0.0720644481
blaffen      0.0666273615
blinken      0.0452859616
bocht       -0.0208467019
bonzen       0.1779355838
boodschap    0.0027313764
bord        -0.0747432455
broek       -0.1352857758
broer        0.0149900742
brok         0.0350749656
brullen     -0.0602780645
buit        -0.0972509626
bukken       0.1055088293
cent        -0.1117035758
deken        0.0644954935
douche       0.0036381350
durven       0.0378583315
dwingen      0.0985062914
echo         0.0441164339
emmer       -0.1827732107
flitsen      0.1099284571
fluisteren  -0.0402365298
fruit       -0.1418218259
gapen        0.0790988060
garage       0.0573048084
giechelen    0.0744790481
gieten       0.0051786877
gillen      -0.0720853650
glinsteren   0.1611677965
gloeien     -0.0006420434
gluren       0.0569286145
graan       -0.0292549369
grap        -0.0532858065
grijns       0.0594641835
grijnzen     0.0898645421
grinniken    0.0079788370
groeten      0.0101844190
grommen      0.0275969175
grot        -0.0824446830
hijgen      -0.0196344803
hijsen      -0.0102253868
horizon      0.0651420746
horloge      0.0999756095
insekt       0.1136356311
jagen       -0.0790522963
juichen      0.0443482373
kanon        0.0562395943
karton       0.0801699947
karwei       0.1548301850
kerel        0.0598380633
ketel        0.1016535893
kilo        -0.1381536047
kin         -0.1042770699
klagen       0.0457694174
klant       -0.0086262023
knagen       0.0485373649
kneden       0.1201589549
knielen      0.1126815917
knipperen    0.1517693419
knol        -0.0174397117
koffer      -0.0616477091
koning      -0.1281543729
koren        0.1131955273
korst       -0.0287838781
kraag       -0.0440020299
kreunen     -0.0609515083
krijsen      0.1006712741
krimpen      0.0615385705
kudde       -0.0508501525
kus         -0.1843313504
ladder       0.0222257557
laden       -0.0021878554
lawaai      -0.0365457444
leunen      -0.0605402731
liegen       0.0188475617
lijden       0.1098908845
liter        0.0032587258
loeren      -0.0312888887
manier      -0.0597143638
matras       0.0594742474
matroos      0.0289956581
melden      -0.0823024077
mengen       0.0704723994
metselen     0.0833313563
minuut      -0.0474364720
mompelen     0.0518466679
mouw        -0.0771313614
mus         -0.1219554377
muts        -0.0893368820
neef        -0.1088691002
ober        -0.0386440623
oever        0.0529884979
oom         -0.2501263391
paradijs     0.1035461642
parfum       0.1300401079
park        -0.1898363453
pet         -0.2387002465
piepen      -0.0617037204
pijl        -0.1524056501
piloot      -0.0307178077
plafond      0.0550323655
plein       -0.1062308115
plek        -0.1071375138
plezier      0.0271274116
plukken      0.0246629318
poes        -0.3211252786
poos        -0.0604537823
proberen     0.0865032420
raket       -0.0305182572
rekenen     -0.0678917356
rest        -0.0522567305
rij         -0.1152876283
rijst        0.0074512884
rillen      -0.0195288176
rinkelen     0.1137929926
ruiken      -0.1270553529
ruzie       -0.0531441298
schamen      0.1394000041
schande      0.1012821240
schelden     0.0380243513
schitteren   0.2030268425
schoot       0.0370187782
schrapen     0.1279871976
sissen       0.0882860501
slikken      0.0997938898
sloot       -0.1050037645
smeken       0.0198952857
smijten      0.0746374741
snauwen      0.1000946006
snikken      0.0646164112
snor        -0.1365519060
snuiven      0.1266264774
sok         -0.1988610956
spijten     -0.0127989874
spleet       0.0974313437
sprookje    -0.0829790800
spul         0.0727633882
stampen      0.0670943244
staren       0.1351586609
stier       -0.0508508015
stinken      0.1052158188
stoep        0.0192434202
stoken       0.1689559126
strekken     0.1158477946
struikelen   0.1168544362
stuiven      0.1212319937
taart       -0.1674119915
tante       -0.0603503035
teen        -0.0710505994
temperatuur  0.2229739230
trots       -0.0615712834
trui        -0.0825829037
turen        0.0756005171
ui          -0.1136609762
vaas        -0.2255921528
vacht        0.0115724128
verdriet    -0.1118314783
verrassen    0.1253446671
vijver       0.0261143860
villa        0.0273855995
vork        -0.0892530467
vuist       -0.0905227220
wang        -0.0534576374
wapperen     0.0518450719
weven        0.0248082646
wiegen      -0.0319488208
worm        -0.0828325787
worstelen    0.0929385197
woud        -0.0622268625
zeuren      -0.0770968651
zuigen      -0.0493489334
zwaard      -0.0246543439
zwemmen     -0.1579047535
zweven       0.0106800811
zwijgen      0.0054364575

$Subject
    (Intercept)
S10 -0.01114527
S12 -0.17835276
S13 -0.07971401
S14  0.16302133
S15 -0.15054170
S16  0.02901146
S18  0.01322766
S2   0.10030362
S20  0.12988077
S21 -0.02441368
S22  0.10534709
S26 -0.23647577
S27  0.17240726
S28 -0.07967623
S29  0.13399079
S3  -0.15511963
S30  0.17107756
S31 -0.04131071
S32  0.19187719
S33 -0.20276061
S34 -0.36079186
S35 -0.01248947
S37 -0.09568015
S39  0.03243001
S40  0.04935140
S43  0.08565865
S46 -0.19972929
S47 -0.01513195
S48  0.03499562
S49 -0.06006614
S51  0.05509955
S52 -0.08016102
S53 -0.10935698
S54 -0.08940870
S57 -0.03362590
S58  0.07610907
S59 -0.07817729
S60  0.03002117
S61 -0.18360230
S62  0.08128662
S63 -0.09115206
S64  0.09495314
S65 -0.04681862
S66  0.23863772
S67  0.01930349
S68  0.03687130
S69 -0.12728725
S7   0.18998541
S70 -0.04493750
S71  0.11866950
S72  0.09710285
S73  0.14082743
S74 -0.11915647
S75 -0.15241258
S76 -0.07439909
S77  0.08911369
S78  0.01982794
S79  0.22601634
S8   0.20748937

with conditional variances for “Word” “Subject”
```

However, this is a very long list, and may be better to just visualize instead. We can do this with the lattice package with the `dotplot` function, using `dotplot(ranef(fit))`.

```
lattice::dotplot(ranef(fit))[1]
lattice::dotplot(ranef(fit))[2]
```

Each plot is shown below:

[image]
[image]

This shows how much each word and each subject shifts from the intercept. While here the variation is quite small, you can see where the variation is occurring.

#### Inferential Testing

If you are looking for some form of inferential test, this is a hairy subject which stretches the definition of random effects and what they mean in a model. [The FAQ by Ben Bolker](https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html) discusses this in some part with regards to model comparison of random effects. There are also random effects splines in GAMMs that include a default significance test, but what that means is likely not going to be helpful unless you have some very specific purpose for doing this. There is [a post here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/597183/345611) that talks about GLMM and GAMM RE significance testing which illustrates part of the issue with this.